# Object destructuring for components

Tags: svelte

I want to be able to destructure an object when I pass it to Svelte component. Something like this?

```
var o = { item: "bread", count: 12 } 
<Component ...object>
```

within Component

```
<b>{{item}}:</b> {{count}}
```

Currently it seems I have to do it manually like this

```
<Thing item={{thing.item}} count={{thing.count}} />
```

Answer (score 0):

There was a [discussion about this](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/pull/280) a while back, and we decided to hold off implementing spread attributes at the time because of concerns over how it would impact the static analysis Svelte does. It's certainly still open for debate though.

Something that might help is if we added destructing in `each` blocks, as it would then mean we could use the compact `:foo` (equivalent to `foo='{{foo}}'`) like so:

```js
{{#each things as {item, count} }}
  <Thing :item :count/>
{{/each}}
```

There isn't currently an open issue for that, but you should definitely feel welcome to create one! I could see us doing that at some point.